# Ошибка при запуске сервиса

Tags: java, android, android-service

Изучаю service, и возник вопрос по-поводу, передачи данных между сервисом и активити. Нашел [этот урок](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/160-urok-95-service-obratnaja-svjaz-s-pomoschju-pendingintent.html), и сделал все как в нем описано. Но при вызове сервиса - выбрасывает просто с программы, при этом в логах не пишет никаких exeption или ошибок. Просто такой диалог , и закрывается программа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Вот мой код:

***активити:***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int TASK1_CODE = 1;
    private final int TASK2_CODE = 2;
    private final int TASK3_CODE = 3;

    public final static int STATUS_START = 100;
    public final static int STATUS_FINISH = 200;

    public static final String PARAM_TIME = "TIME";
    public static final String PARAM_PINTENT = "PINTENT";
    public static final String PARAM_RESULT = "RESULT";

    private TextView textTask1, textTask2, textTask3;
    private Button startService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textTask1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task1);
        textTask1.setText("task 1 ");

        textTask2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task2);
        textTask2.setText("task 2");

        textTask3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task3);
        textTask3.setText("task 3");

        startService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClickStart();
            }
        });


    }


    private void onClickStart(){
        PendingIntent pi;
        Intent intent;

        pi = createPendingResult(TASK1_CODE, null, 0);
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class)
                .putExtra(PARAM_TIME, 7)
                .putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);
        startService(intent);

        pi = createPendingResult(TASK2_CODE, null, 0);
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class)
                .putExtra(PARAM_TIME, 4)
                .putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);
        startService(intent);

        pi = createPendingResult(TASK3_CODE, null, 0);
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class)
                .putExtra(PARAM_TIME, 6)
                .putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);
        startService(intent);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == STATUS_START){
            switch (requestCode){
                case TASK1_CODE:{
                    textTask1.setText("task 1 start");
                    break;
                }
                case TASK2_CODE:{
                    textTask2.setText("task 2 start");
                    break;
                }
                case TASK3_CODE:{
                    textTask3.setText("task 3 start");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (resultCode == STATUS_FINISH){
            int result = data.getIntExtra(PARAM_RESULT, 0);
            switch (requestCode){
                case TASK1_CODE:{
                    textTask1.setText("task 1 finish, result = " + result );
                    break;
                }
                case TASK2_CODE:{
                    textTask2.setText("task 2 finish, result = " + result);
                    break;
                }
                case TASK3_CODE:{
                    textTask3.setText("task 3 finish , result = " + result);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

***и сервис:***

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final String LOG = "MYSERVICELOG";
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG, "onCreate");
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG, "onDestroy");
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG, "onStartCommand");
        int time = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_TIME, 1);
        PendingIntent pi = intent.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_PINTENT);

        MyRun myRun = new MyRun(time, startId, pi);
        executorService.execute(myRun);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    class MyRun implements Runnable{

        private int time, startId;
        private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        public MyRun(int time, int startId, PendingIntent pendingIntent){
            this.time = time;
            this.startId = startId;
            this.pendingIntent = pendingIntent;
            Log.d(LOG, "MyRun# " + startId + " created");
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(LOG, "MyRun# " + startId + " time: " + time + " start");
            try {
                pendingIntent.send(MainActivity.STATUS_START);

                 TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(time);
                Intent intent = new Intent()
                        .putExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_RESULT, time *100);
                pendingIntent.send(MyService.this, MainActivity.STATUS_FINISH, intent);

            }catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException ce){
                ce.getStackTrace();
            }catch (InterruptedException ie){
                ie.getStackTrace();
            }
            stop();

        }

        private void stop(){
            Log.d(LOG, "MyService# " + startId + " stoped" );
            stopSelfResult(startId);
        }


    }

}
```

**В чем может быть проблема ??**

***Помогите, не могу понять !!***

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем вы сервис трижды подряд запускаете. И скорее всего PendingIntent нельзя через Bundle передать.

Comment: А что в логах-то?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, та просто когда выбрасывает с программы - не печатает трассировку стека. Вот и не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я просто делал по примеру(я навел ссылку в вопросе), и там это сделано для демонстрации(скорее всего), того как работает метод stopSelfResult(startId). Но почему-то у меня программа вылетает, при запуске сервиса при этом в логе не печатает трассировку стека...и поэтому не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Comment: Ну... Может у вас сервис в манифесте не прописан... Ну и попробуйте локализовать проблему - уберите из сервиса всё лишнее и оставьте только его запуск безо всяких данных. А потом добавляйте код. Увидете где начнёт падать. Сейчас код выглядит странно, но явных ошибок не видать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, буду разбираться )

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, локализовал и разобрался )) Спасибо за отклик )

Comment: @Maybe_V, было б хорошо, если б вы хотя бы кратко решение и описание проблемы в ответе описали - может ещё кому-то поможет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сделано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в инициализации  `PendingIntent`, точнее в том что я передавал `null`  вместо интента в метод `createPendingResult(TASK1_CODE, null, 0)`.

Проблема решилась после замены кода:

```
pi = createPendingResult(TASK1_CODE, null, 0);
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class)
                .putExtra(PARAM_TIME, 7)
                .putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);
        startService(intent);
```

на код:

```
pi = createPendingResult(TASK1_CODE, new Intent(), 0);
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class)
                .putExtra(PARAM_TIME, 7)
                .putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);
        startService(intent);
```